# Figure out what files are loaded and in which order

Tags: php, hhvm

Sidenode: I'm playing around with HHVM and stuck on some point where it gets to complex for me. So I'm searching some new tips and hope that someone could help me.My goal is to build HHVM from source with the laravel Framework as **HHVM-extension**. So all classes should be included in systemlib.php.

*Has anyone an idea to figure out what files are loaded and in which order?*

To get the included files, I added an `echo $file;` before all includes in the differend autoloader functions.
But it seems that Classes that are "included" with the `use` command are not loaded by the autoloader and therefore not comming up in the echo's. Also the Classes from `extends` and `implements`.

I would be really thankfull for any kind of answers and ideas, it would be really cool if it would work somehow.

Comment: "My goal is to build HHVM from source with the laravel Framework as HHVM-extension. So all classes should be included in systemlib.php." Why are you trying to do this, this seems like an incredibly bizarre thing to do. Why not just run Laravel as PHP code like anything else?

Comment: Maybe just because I'm an incredibly guy with bizarre ideas who just wants to figure out how much faster laravel would run without all these includes ;)
If hhvm has laravel as an extension, no include files have to be read and interpreted at every request. I just want to give it a try.

Comment: The same loading and caching mechanisms apply to systemlib just as much as they do to outside code. If you want to flatten out the includes, go for it (though I'd be absolutely shocked if they were a significant performance hit). But moving it into systemlib will do nothing at all perf-wise, just make your life a lot harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [get_included_files()](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) both in `HHVM` and `PHP` to get list of loaded script files in order of their reading as array of filenames.